# Обход Singleton с помощью Reflection Api

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, рефлексия, шаблон-одиночка

Нашел способ обхода стандартной реализации паттена Singletion с помощью php Reflection Api.

Стандартная реализация выглядит примерно так:

```
class Singleton {
    static private $instance = null;
    private function __construct() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  // Защищаем от создания через new Singleton
    private function __clone() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  // Защищаем от создания через клонирование
    private function __wakeup() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  // Защищаем от создания через unserialize

    static public function getInstance() {
        return 
        self::$instance===null
            ? self::$instance = new static()//new self()
            : self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Используя ReflectionClass мы можем создать экземпляр объекта нужного нам класса, в том числе [в обход метода](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php) `__construct()`

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('className');
$third = $ref->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
```

Вот полный пример, в котором первые 2 объекта Singleton создаются стандартным способом, а третий через Reflection

```
class Singleton {
    static private $instance = null;
    private function __construct() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  // Защищаем от создания через new Singleton
    private function __clone() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  // Защищаем от создания через клонирование
    private function __wakeup() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }  // Защищаем от создания через unserialize

    private $value = "Изначальное значение свойства";

    static public function getInstance() {
        return 
        self::$instance===null
            ? self::$instance = new static()//new self()
            : self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * обновить значение приватного свойства
     * @param [type] $v [description]
     */
    public function setValue($v) {
        $this->value = $v;
    }

    /**
     * получить значение приватного свойства
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$first = Singleton::getInstance();
$first->setValue('Обновленное значение свойства');
var_dump('$first->getValue: ' . $first->getValue());

$second = Singleton::getInstance();
var_dump('$sceond->getValue: ' . $second->getValue());
var_dump('$first===$second: '.(($first===$second)? 'true':'false'));

$ref = new ReflectionClass('Singleton');
$third = $ref->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
var_dump('$third->getValue: ' . $third->getValue());
var_dump('$third instanceof Singleton: ' . (($third instanceof Singleton)? 'true':'false'));
var_dump('$third===$second: '.(($third===$second)? 'true':'false'));
```

В итоге мы видим, что третий объект является инстансом класса Singleton, но обладает другими свойствами.

```
$ php reflection.php 
"$first->getValue: Обновленное значение свойства"
"$sceond->getValue: Обновленное значение свойства"
"$first===$second: true"
"$third->getValue: Изначальное значение свойства"
"$third instanceof Singleton: true"
"$third===$second: false"
```

Внимание вопрос: есть ли возможность создать полностью защищенный синглтон, что бы избежать в том числе и такую возможность создания инстанса в обход стандартной реализации.

Comment: [Does reflection breaks the idea of private methods, because private methods can be access outside of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3300680/2881286)

Comment: Но такая защита бесполезна?

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться - зачем? Синглтон обычно делают с определенными целями (например когда надо закешировать коннект к БД, а статики боятся). Если какой-то разработчик дошел до такой жизни, что начал "ломать" логику синглтона с помощью рефлексии, то это означает только одно - ему реально ооочень надо, а значит данный паттерн изначально был выбран неверно.

Comment: Солидарен с вами, если кто то хочет сломать синглтон с помощью рефлекшен - это беда. Вопрос немного в другом, как защитить свой код от внешнего внешнего вмешательства.

Comment: какое внешнее вмешательство вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Ну слушайте, вариантов много, достаточно включить фантазию. Суть не в этом, а в том, возможно ли сделать нормальный синглтон, который нельзя будет пересоздать?

Comment: Ну вот хоть один вариант такого злостного вмешательства приведите? использовать рефлексию можно только в том случае, если у человека есть доступ к вашему коду, а в этом случае гораздо проще переделать класс, чем так извращаться

Comment: Что на счет Zend Guard? Используем его, в итоге тот кто пользуется кодом знает только общий интерфейс системы, соответственно если предположим какой то из методов этого интерфейса принимает определенный синглтон в качестве аргумента, его можно будет подделать. Я понимаю о чем вы хотите сказать, что использовать рефлекшен в качестве инструмента НЕ для дебага - изначально плохая идея, но все-таки способ защитить свой код от этого... Ведь в это не единственный метод, который противоречит принципам ооп, Тот же setAccessible - это вообще не вероятное зло!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Паттерны проектирования существуют для облегчения разработки и сопровождения кода, а не для того, чтобы "запретить и не пущать".

Если в какой-то момент разработчик пал столь низко, что решил использовать в рабочем коде рефлексию, то это в большинстве случаев (не рассматриваем особые случаи, типа тестов, фреймворков и т.д.) говорит о больших проблемах. А уж если с помощью рефлексии стали "ломать" синглтон, то это повод очень всерьез задуматься, нужен ли он там.

Что касается мифического "внешнего вмешательства". Использовать рефлексию может только а) человек, который знает, что это такое, б) имеющий доступ к вашему коду и с) если ему действительно понадобилось использовать рефлексию. Как вы заметили, условие б) в 99.99% случаев позволяет обойтись вообще без рефлексии. А остальные 0.01% случаев выпадают на условие с), например для написания экзотических тестов

PS Отвечая на вопрос. Reflection для того и создавался, чтобы можно было ковыряться в кишках объектов и собирать любых франкенштейнов. Не напишите вы синглтон, который будет защищен от рефлексии.